# Multiple lines grep

Tags: bash, filter, grep, cygwin

I got a file with a schema like this:

```
172.18.0.7
172.18.0.9
172.18.0.8
172.18.0.7
172.18.0.9
172.18.0.8
172.18.0.7
172.18.0.9
172.18.0.8
172.18.0.7
172.18.0.9
172.18.0.8
```

> So its 7->9->8->7->9->8->7->9->8->7->9->8->7->9->8 ... at its end.

**I want to get the lines where this schema is different. E.g. `7->8->9`:**

```
172.18.0.7
172.18.0.8
172.18.0.9
```

As the file got something about 100000 lines I'd like to use grep to filter them.

I tried something like this:

> grep -Pzl "172.18.0.7*\n 172.18.0.9*\n 172.18.0.8*\n"

which did not work out properly. I wanted to find a pattern which fits the schema mentioned first.

Comment: Not clear, please do mention more details for your samples and let us know then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk -v RS='\n*[0-9.]+7\n[0-9.]+9\n[0-9.]+8\n' NF file
```

The record separator `RS` is set such that it matches 3 lines having digits and dots and that finishing respectively with `7`, `9`, `8` (in this order).

The output record `ORS` separator being (the default one) `\n`, the input script (only `NF`) prints all non empty lines (that don't match `RS`).

Comment: When OP only wants to look to the last digit for controlling the matches, the solution is right, When OP also wants to find lines like `special172.18.0.7`, `111.11.1.7` and `172.18.0.888888888` as a different schema, your solution needs some refinement.

Answer (score 0):

GNU sed 4.2 supports `-z`:

```
sed -z 's/172.18.0.7\n172.18.0.9\n172.18.0.8\n//g' file
```

This solution will fail when you the first line of a potential set of three is like

```
some_other_chars_before_172.18.0.7
```

When you add `\n` in the beginning of the match, you need to remove the last `\n` to find 2 sets without something in between, but that would allow the last line ending with

```
172.18.0.8_and_more_characters
```

It looks like a deadlock, but you can modify your input to Windows style and match smart:

```
 sed -rz 's/\n/\r\n/g;s/(\n|^)172.18.0.7\r\n172.18.0.9\r\n172.18.0.8\r//g;s/\r//g' file
```